# libglib2.0 errors on 11.10 upgrade and installing ia32-libs

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, 64-bit, 32-bit

Ran through the upgrade to 11.10 and bunch of errors came back.  After some initial diagnosis and autoremove via apt-get, I've still got 17 packages that won't install.  Running dpkg --audit gives me:

```
The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 libglib2.0-0:i386    GLib library of C routines
```

So I run that, and get the following:

```
sudo dpkg --configure libglib2.0-0:i386
Setting up libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.30.0-0ubuntu4) ...
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/glib-compile-schemas: error while loading shared                  libraries: libglib-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/gio-querymodules: error while loading shared   libraries: libglib-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglib2.0-0:i386
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE: So, I was able to clear some errors, but now I can reproduce this when trying to install ia32-libs.

UPDATE2:

```
ldd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/glib-compile-schemas
  linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf779d000)
  libglib-2.0.so.0 => not found
  libc.so.6 => /opt/McAfee/runtime/2.0/lib/libc.so.6 (0xf767b000)
  /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf779e000)

ldd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/gio-querymodules 
  linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf76f2000)
  libglib-2.0.so.0 => not found
  libgobject-2.0.so.0 => not found
  libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => not found
  libgio-2.0.so.0 => not found
  libc.so.6 => /opt/McAfee/runtime/2.0/lib/libc.so.6 (0xf75cf000)
  /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf76f3000)
```

grep -r . /etc/ld.so.conf*:

```
/etc/ld.so.conf:include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/biarch-compat.conf:# Legacy biarch compatibility support
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/biarch-compat.conf:/lib32
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/biarch-compat.conf:/usr/lib32
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf:/usr/lib/nvidia-current-updates
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current-updates
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/i686-linux-gnu.conf:# Multiarch support
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/i686-linux-gnu.conf:/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/i686-linux-gnu.conf:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/i686-linux-gnu.conf:/lib/i686-linux-gnu
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/i686-linux-gnu.conf:/usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia_settings.conf:/usr/lib/nvidia-settings-updates
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf:# libc default configuration
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf:/usr/local/lib
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf:# Multiarch support
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

These files exist:

```
/lib32/libglib-2.0.so.0 -> libglib-2.0.so.0.3000.0
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 -> libglib-2.0.so.0.3000.0
/usr/lib32/libgobject-2.0.so.0 -> libgobject-2.0.so.0.3000.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 -> libgobject-2.0.so.0.3000.0
```

More info:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, $LD_PRELOAD, $PATH:
, , /home/vrigdon/bin:/home/vrigdon/apache-maven-3.0.3/bin:/home/vrigdon/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin:/home/vrigdon/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/vrigdon/dev/lib/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools:/home/vrigdon/gradle-1.0-milestone-3/bin
```

Comment: Please add the output of `ldd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/glib-compile-schemas`. Repeat this for all paths on which you've a shared library error.

Comment: @Lekensteyn I've added the outputs.

Comment: Do `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0`, `/usr/lib32/libgobject-2.0.so.0`, `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0` and `/lib32/libglib-2.0.so.0` exist? Please add the output of `grep -r . /etc/ld.so.conf*` to your question.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Updated again.  Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Do you really need McAfee? It has probably something to do with it. Please add the result of: `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, $LD_PRELOAD, $PATH`

Comment: I don't really want McAfee but it's a requirement in the short term; I'll try to get rid of it and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never solved this, as I re-installed the OS, but I'm pretty sure it was the McAfee install.